# Implicit per-container storage in Docker with MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a container with MySQL that is configured to start with "-v /data:/var/lib/mysql" and therefore persists data between container restarts in the separate folder. Although this approach has some drawbacks, in particular, the user may not have write permissions for a specified directory. How exactly container should be reconfigured in order to use Docker's implicit per-container storage to save MySQL data in the /var/lib/docker/volumes in order to reuse it after the container is stopped and started again? Or is it better to consider another persistence options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you show is called `bind mounts`.

What you request is called `volumes`.

Just create volume and connect it

```
docker volume create foo
docker run ... -v foo:/var/lib/mysql <image> <command>
```

And you've done it! You can connect it to many containers at will.